# instance frame type when not in a function error

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game in which objects spawn on the map in a certain location and I have multiple functions for different objects and needed a reference so I put my code outside of the function to widen its scope but now I get an error that says

```
Instance type 'frame' cannot be used on type 'Levelunit'
```

If i put it back into the function it is completely fine but it seems to have a problem when I put it outside the function. Here is my code:

```
let yAxisSpawnLocations: [CGFloat] = [0]
let xAxisSpawnLocations: [CGFloat] = {

    var spawnLocations:[CGFloat] = []   //Create 5 possible spawn locations
    let numberOfNodes = 5

    for i in 0...numberOfNodes - 1 {

        var xPosition = (frame.maxX) / CGFloat((numberOfNodes - 1)) * CGFloat(i)

        xPosition += thePlayer.size.width/2

        xPosition -= frame.maxX/1.6
        spawnLocations.append( xPosition )

    }

    return spawnLocations

}()
```

I looked it up and didn't quite understand the answer given. Could someone tell me what i'm doing wrong please.

BTW, LevelUnit is the name of my class.

Comment: If you provide more info about Levelunit class I could comment more about if is it a good idea to override its initializer and initialize `xSpawningLocation` property there. I guess that is a subclass of a `SKScene`, and you initialize it using fileNamed convenience initializer, right? But anyways, check out my answer. It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `self` before `Levelunit` has be fully initialized. For example, this is one place where you use `self` implicitly:

```
var xPosition = (frame.maxX) / CGFloat((numberOfNodes - 1)) * CGFloat(i)
```

it is the same as:

```
var xPosition = (self.frame.maxX) / CGFloat((numberOfNodes - 1)) * CGFloat(i)
```

So, what you can do is to initialize this property at `Levelunit` initializer (which I would skip if you don't want to have a dance with automatic initializer inheritance rules), or to initialize it in `didMoveToView`, which will work fine. If I am not wrong, `Levelunit` is probably subclass of a SKScene, right? If so, just do this:

```
//Define a property of Levelunit like this

 var xAxisSpawnLocations:[CGFloat] = []
```

Then just initialize it inside of `didMoveToView`:

```
let numberOfNodes = 5

for i in 0...numberOfNodes - 1 {

    var xPosition = (self.frame.maxX) / CGFloat((numberOfNodes - 1)) * CGFloat(i)

    xPosition += thePlayer.size.width/2
    xPosition -= frame.maxX/1.6
    xAxisSpawnLocations.append( xPosition )

}
```

Comment: thanks that worked I was wondering if you could help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434190/taking-an-array-option-out-for-one-cycle